# c# record short syntax private members

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

This is not legal (why?):

```
record Rec(int Field1, string Field2, private int PrivateField) { .. };
```

Just to have the private field I now need to switch to the tedious long form:

```
record Rec 
{
  public int Field1 { get; init; }
  public string Field2  { get; init; }
  int PrivateField  { get; init; } 

  public Bla(int field1, string field2, int privateField) 
  {
    Field1=field1;
    Field2 = field2;
    PrivateField = privateField;
  }

  ...
}
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Simple: `private` is not allowed in a primary constructor.

Comment: @madreflection I said that in the first line

Comment: But you asked *"This is not legal (why?):"* so not sure what you expected.

Comment: I am hoping for some clever way to use the shorthand to create private member, I also wonder _why_ is this not allowed

Comment: Nope. The primary constructor syntax is for DTO-like types with all public properties.

Comment: About the "why": the point of the record shortcut feature was to provide a simpler alternative for initialisation + declaration for "data" classes / struct which are just a public list of properties. For more you'd need to ask the language team, but the ultimate reason is "because the language is currently designed as such".

Comment: for the more clever way, I don't think we can really answer unless you provide your actual goal. For this few-liners example, you should write the whole code above, and not overthink it. If you have a particular situation more complex, maybe that's worth investigating, but we need more info.

Comment: thanks @Pac0 I was wondering if maybe there can be away using attributes which I can add to the short syntax

Comment: Not natively as far as I know.

Comment: Why? Support for access modifiers has never been available via parameters. Crazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest:

```cs
record Rec(int Field1, string Field2)
{
    int PrivateField;
};
```

Comment: the issue here is that the compiler generated ctor will not include PrivateField which is what I want

Comment: @kofifus You could add an additional constructor `public Rec(int field1, string field2, int privateField) : this (field1, field2) => PrivateField = privateField;`

Comment: How are you going to init private PrivatefField?

Comment: Serge. Through public function, it n't? i.g.,  public string Something() => $"{Field1} | {PrivateField}";

Comment: You could also consider a closure to keep some variables private inside an immutable type - It's just an idea

Answer (score 3):

you can create an abstract base record with a protected field. It will behavior the same way as a private one

```
public record Rec(int Field1, string Field2, int PrivateField) : Base(PrivateField)

public abstract record Base
{
    protected int  PrivateField; //or { get; init; }

    public Base(int privateField)
    {
        PrivateField=privateField;
    }
}
```